# Create a 3-dimension list from two 2-dimension lists with a common element in each

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of fruits and weight tuple pairs.

```
[('apple', 5), ('banana', 9), ('coconut', 14)...]
```

Let's say I also have a list of fruits and price pairs.

```
[('apple', 0.99), ('banana', 1.24), ('coconut', 3.20)...]
```

How can I get a list of a fruit, weight, and prices? We can assume both lists have the same fruits. Bonus points for answers that don't require external modules.

Comment: Are both lists always in corresponding order?

Comment: Not necessarily, but sorting is trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
weights = [('apple', 5), ('banana', 9), ('coconut', 14)]
prices  = [('apple', 0.99), ('banana', 1.24), ('coconut', 3.20)]
```

You can convert both the lists to dictionaries, with fruits as keys, using dictionary comprehension

```
weights = {fruit:weight for fruit, weight in weights}
prices  = {fruit:price for fruit, price in prices}
```

This step can be simply written with `dict` function, like this

```
weights, prices = dict(weights), dict(prices)
```

and then the list construction is trivial, with list comprehension

```
print [(fruit, weights[fruit], prices[fruit]) for fruit in weights]
# [('coconut', 14, 3.2), ('apple', 5, 0.99), ('banana', 9, 1.24)]
```

Comment: Or simply ``data1 = dict(data1)``?

Answer (score 0):

You could do (assuming they are correspondingly ordered at this point):

```
>>> list1 = [('apple', 5), ('banana', 9), ('coconut', 14)]
>>> list2 = [('apple', 0.99), ('banana', 1.24), ('coconut', 3.20)]
>>> 
>>> [x+y for x, y in zip(list1, [(t[1],) for t in list2])]
[('apple', 5, 0.99), ('banana', 9, 1.24), ('coconut', 14, 3.2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
weights = [('apple', 5), ('banana', 9), ('coconut', 14)]
prices = [('apple', 0.99), ('banana', 1.24), ('coconut', 3.20)]
```

You can do it by simple List Comprehension:

```
[(fruit, weight, dict(prices)[fruit]) for fruit, weight in weights]
```

Edit: It may be ineffective for large lists. This should be better:

```
prices_dict = dict(prices)
[(fruit, weight, prices_dict[fruit]) for fruit, weight in weights]
```